# Connect to SSRS from different computer on home network

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am trying to access the SSRS web portal. I have SQL Server and Report Server installed on laptop with Windows 10. I want to access this from another laptop running windows 11 that is connected to the same home internet network.

The web portal works fine when I access it from the computer running Report Server:

[image]

But when I try to access the url from another the other computer on the same network, the page just doesn't load:

[image]

I tried to follow the instructions from this site: https://askgarth.com/blog/why-cant-i-access-my-ssrs-site-remotely/

I opened port 80 TCP protocol in windows firewall to allow connections.

I think that the issue may be the profile to which the rule applies:

[image]

The instructions I tried to follow said to open up the Domain. I also tried the Private option and still no luck.

I'm nervous about opening up ports on my firewall. But how can I set this up to access the Report Server from another computer on my network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked my setup which is basically the same...

- 'Server' Desktop running Windows 10 Pro: Hosts SQL Server 2019 and SSRS
- 'Client' Desktop running Windows 11: Accessing SSRS from here

I checked the 'server' PC and the only SQL specific ports that are open are TCP port 1433 to allow me to access the database engine via SSMS etc from the 'client' PC and TCP port 80 (both are setup to domain + private although domain should be irrelevant)

I don't normally access the SSRS portal from the 'client' but it did work in as far as it said I do not have access to any reports, but it was showing the web portal page itself just fine.

You have probably done all this but here are a few things you could try...

1. Check if your version of Win10 is supported. If it's Win10 home for example it may not support everything required but this is just a guess.
2. Ping the server from the host and make sure you get a response (assuming PING response has not been turned off)
3. Check server firewall allows incoming on ports TCP 80 and TCP 1433 (1433 should not be required but you can always switch this off later)
4. Attempt access using the server ip e.g. http://192.168.1.123/Reports
5. If this all fails, turn off the windows firewall and test again. You can always disconnect your router from the internet whilst you do this to be safe. If this works then you at least know it's a firewall issue.
6. Check if you have any 3rd party anti-virus software that might be acting as a firewall - turn off and test again.

Comment: It looks like using the server ip in the url worked (#4 suggestion). Thank you for your help Alan! Do you know how to set it up to use the server name instead of the IP address?

Comment: If network discovery is setup on both machines then it should work, look in windows explorer under network and see if you can see the server there. If not check network discovery setting on the server. The other option is to add an entry into the hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`). Edit this file on the client pc and add an entry for your server and it's IP. e.g. 1`92.168.1.123 AnyNameHere` .  `AnyNameHere` cam be any valid name windows will just swap this for the IP address, its like a local DNS entry